# How do I apply the fade filter after a CUDA-powered scale with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to apply a fade out filter to a video that is being encoded with the h264_nvenc encoder.

This:
`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a copy -vf scale_cuda=-1:720,hwdownload,fade=t=out:st=24:d=0.5,hwupload -y output.mp4`

fails with this error message:

```
[hwdownload @ 0000028b4c8c7ea0] Invalid output format yuv420p for hwframe download.
[Parsed_hwdownload_1 @ 0000028b4d833620] Failed to configure output pad on 
Parsed_hwdownload_1
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

I haven't really worked with ffmpeg's hardware acceleration features before, and apparently no one else has, either. At least no one has bothered documenting them.

I'd be incredibly grateful for any help with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, although indeed not well documented, the doc is there somehow.

Since the error says `Invalid output format yuv420p for hwframe download`, we need to find a way to change the pixel format for the filter.

[FFmpeg filter document](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hwdownload) says:

> Not all formats will be supported on the output - it may be necessary to **insert an additional format filter immediately following in the graph** to get the output in a supported format.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a copy -vf scale_cuda=-1:720,hwdownload,format=nv12,fade=t=out:st=24:d=0.5,hwupload -y output.mp4
```

Comment: I would have never guessed that. Thanks!

Comment: @halfelf Should your example also work with the transpose filter? When I use it, I get green horizontal lines across the output.

Comment: @JonG Strange, I don't know why those green lines occur. I've tried `rotate` filter and it works. You could apply `rotate=PI/2`, `rotate=-PI/2` or just PI to replace transpose filter.